# kafka connect sql server incremental changes from cdc

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am very new to Kafka (started reading and setting up in my Sandbox environment from just a week) and trying to setup SQL Server JDBC connector. 
I have setup Confluent community as per confluent guide and installed io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector using confluent-hub
I enabled CDC on SQL Server Database and required table and it is working fine.

I have tried following connectors (one at-a-time):

1. io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
2. io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector

both are loading fine with status of connector and task running fine with no errors as seen below:

[image: connector status]

Here is my io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector confuguration

```
{
"name": "mssql-connector",
"config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "CreatedDateTime",
        "query": "select * from dbo.sampletable",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "table.types": "TABLE",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "topic.prefix": "data_",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://SQL2016:1433;databaseName=sampledb",
        "connection.user": "kafka",
        "connection.password": "kafkaPassword@789",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "poll.interval.ms": "5000",
        "table.poll.interval.ms": "120000"
    }
}
```

Here is my io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector connector

```
{
 "name": "mssql-connector",
 "config": {
     "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
     "tasks.max" : "1",
     "database.server.name" : "SQL2016",
     "database.hostname" : "SQL2016",
     "database.port" : "1433",
     "database.user" : "kafka",
     "database.password" : "kafkaPassword@789",
     "database.dbname" : "sampleDb",
     "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafkanode1:9092",
     "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.sampleDb"
     }
 }
```

Both connectors are creating snapshot of a table in a topic (means it pulls all the rows initially)
but when I make changes to a table "sampletable" (insert/update/delete), those changes are not being pulled to kafka.

can someone please help me understand how to make CDC working with Kafka?

Thanks

Comment: What SQL Server version are you running? Also, can you share example payloads for inserts, deletes, etc. ?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2016 Enterprise. I will create sample payload and post it here

Comment: Have you checked kafka connect logs?

Comment: It would also be useful to provide the steps you followed in order to enable mssql cdc feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to have worked 100%. I am posting answer just in case someone like me stuck on jdbc source connector.

```
{
"name": "piilog-connector",
"config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "mode": "incrementing",       
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://SQL2016:1433;databaseName=SIAudit",
        "connection.user": "kafka",
        "connection.password": "kafkaPassword@789",  
        "query": "select * from dbo.sampletable",
        "incrementing.column.name": "Id",
        "validate.non.null": false,
        "topic.prefix": "data_",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "poll.interval.ms": "5000",
        "table.poll.interval.ms": "5000"
    }
}
```